Error: RangeError [ERR_BUFFER_OUT_OF_BOUNDS] when Fetching Document from Firestore
I'm encountering an error while trying to fetch a user profile document from Firestore using Node.js. Here’s a snippet of my code:
const profileRef = db.collection("profiles").doc(uid);
const profileSnapshot = await profileRef.get();

if (!profileSnapshot.exists) {
  return res.status(404).send({ message: "Profile not found" });
}

const profileInfo = profileSnapshot.data();

When I run my server, I receive the following error:
Error stack: RangeError [ERR_BUFFER_OUT_OF_BOUNDS]: "length" is outside of buffer bounds
    at proto.utf8Write (node:internal/buffer:1066:13)
    at Op.writeStringBuffer [as fn] (/Users/fao/Documents/spotters-api/node_modules/protobufjs/src/writer_buffer.js:61:13)
    at BufferWriter.finish (/Users/fao/Documents/spotters-api/node_modules/protobufjs/src/writer.js:453:14)
    at /Users/fao/Documents/spotters-api/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/build/src/index.js:177:109
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createPackageDefinition (/Users/fao/Documents/spotters-api/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/build/src/index.js:177:39)
    at Object.fromJSON (/Users/fao/Documents/spotters-api/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/build/src/index.js:230:12)
    at GrpcClient.loadProtoJSON (/Users/fao/Documents/spotters-api/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js:228:51)
    at new LocationsClient (/Users/fao/Documents/spotters-api/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/locationService.js:118:32)
    at new FirestoreClient (/Users/fao/Documents/spotters-api/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/v1/firestore_client.js:136:32)
Caused by: Error
    at /Users/fao/Documents/spotters-api/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/index.js:1042:27
    at DisabledTraceUtil.startActiveSpan (/Users/fao/Documents/spotters-api/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/telemetry/disabled-trace-util.js:16:16)
    at Firestore.getAll (/Users/fao/Documents/spotters-api/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/index.js:1033:32)
    at /Users/fao/Documents/spotters-api/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference/document-reference.js:182:36
    at DisabledTraceUtil.startActiveSpan (/Users/fao/Documents/spotters-api/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/telemetry/disabled-trace-util.js:16:16)
    at DocumentReference.get (/Users/fao/Documents/spotters-api/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference/document-reference.js:181:43)
    at getProfilePageModel (/Users/fao/Documents/spotters-api/src/controllers/dataBaseController.js:38:48)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/fao/Documents/spotters-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/fao/Documents/spotters-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:149:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/fao/Documents/spotters-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:119:3)
(node:54380) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

Environment Details:
Node.js version: v22.7.0
package.json:
{
  "name": "spotters-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/firestore": "^7.10.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.21.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^12.5.0"
  }
}

Steps I've Taken:
Verified that the Firestore document exists for the given UID.
Ensured that my Firestore rules allow read access to the profiles collection.
Updated all dependencies to their latest versions.
Additional Information:
The error occurs on the line where I call profileRef.get().
I'm using Express.js for my server.
Can anyone help me understand what might be causing this error and how to resolve it?

If you're using firebase-admin, then you shouldn't add another dependency for "@google-cloud/firestore.  That is automatically included by firebase-admin, which provides a thin wrapper around its API.  If you add it manually, you might have a version mismatch between all the dependencies required by firebase-admin.

I removed @google-cloud/firestore still getting same error

Did you just remove it from package.json, or did you fully uninstall it using your package manager?

I uninstalled it using:
npm uninstall @google-cloud/firestore
Here's the error I’m seeing:
RangeError [ERR_BUFFER_OUT_OF_BOUNDS]: "length" is outside of buffer bounds     at proto.utf8Write (node:internal/buffer:1066:13)     at Op.writeStringBuffer [as fn] 
I've already tried:
Removing node_modules and package-lock.json, then reinstalling everything using npm install.
Verifying that @google-cloud/firestore is no longer listed in my package.json.
Clearing npm cache using npm cache clean --force.

If you're encountering the following error while accessing Firestore with Node.js version 22.7.0:
RangeError [ERR_BUFFER_OUT_OF_BOUNDS]: "length" is outside of buffer bounds
    at proto.utf8Write (node:internal/buffer:1066:13)
    at Op.writeStringBuffer [as fn] (node_modules/protobufjs/src/writer_buffer.js:61:13)

This is a known issue with Node.js version 22.7.0. The problem doesn't occur in earlier versions like Node.js 22.6.0 or 22.4.0.
Solution:
Upgrade to Node.js 22.8.0. The issue has been fixed in this release.
Check this github issue for more detail:
[Firestore] RangeError thrown on Node version 22.7.0
